# How to interpret: Love of something or someone

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, possessives

Saw the phrase "love of fate" and found that it means the quality of loving (or rather embracing) one's fate, I got some questions.

#### Sentences

- A. He has the love of her.
- B. He has the love of hers.
- C. He has her love.
- D. He has the love of life.

#### Questions

1. Does A mean "He loves her?"
2. Does B mean "She loves him?"
3. Is C an equivalent to B?
4. D means he loves his life. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A and B are arguably grammatically valid, but no fluent speaker words it that way. We don't say "He has the love of her", but rather, "He has her love". Which, by the way, means the she loves him: the love that she has to offer has been given to him, so he has her love.

C is valid and common.

D is slightly awkward because of the word "the". It is common to say things like, "He has a love of life". But "the" implies there is only one such love, when in reality presumably everyone could have one. It could make sense, I guess, if you were contrasting it with love of other things. Like, "Some people have the love of money, but others have the love of life." I'd still think it odd, but possible.